# What is the 2D Fourier Transform of this function?

Tags: fourier-transform, 2d

$
f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
1,\hspace{30px} x > 0 \\
0,\hspace{30px} else\\
\end{cases}
$

i.e. $f(x,y)$ is a bi-variate function which is zero everywhere to the left of the y-axis and one everywhere to the right of the y-axis.

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far?

Comment: So far, I applied the standard formula for 2D Fourier Transform with the bounds on integrals for dy going from negative infinity to positive infinity and for dx going from 0 to positive infinity. However, when I evaluated the integrals, the answer I got was infinity.

Comment: Can you write f(x,y) as g(x)h(y), for simple functions g & h?  Then you just need to compute two simple 1D Fourier transforms that should be in any table of transforms.

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/step.php) for the 1D case and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, this is the answer
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+[Piecewise[{{1%2Cx%3E0}%2C{0%2C+x%3C%3D0}}]]

Comment: Copy paste that last link since SE does not recognize all of it. Or just go to wolfram and ask: Fourier transform [Piecewise[{{1,x>0},{0, x<=0}}]]

Comment: This might help: http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/step.php